# android setting different fonts/colors in listview

Tags: android, listview, fonts, colors

I have created a listview with 3 rows in Android. If I would like to set different fonts/colors on the rows, how do I achieve this? So far I have tried different things without any sucess. This is my latest try, I try to set the getComment() to italic, but honestly I have no clue what I am doing :D. Please help!

```
public String toString()
{
return this.getAlias() + " " + this.dateFormat.format(this.getDate()) + "\n" +         (Html.fromHtml("<i>" + this.getComment() + "</i>" + "<br />"));  
}
```

Comment: Try reading this document first http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: You can try creating Custom ArrayAdapter or Baseadpter and inflate views as row.

Comment: Did you solve your ploblem yet? if one of the answers helped you out, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have defined your rows in a xml layout file. You can change the color / style of the text in a TextView with some simple parameters:

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
  android:textStyle="italic"
/>
```

Comment: "I would like to set different fonts/colors on the rows" - not set color and style SAME for each row

Comment: You could create and ArrayAdapter (as suggested by Roy in his answer). In the getView() method you can set the color / style by calling myTextView.setColor(..) / myTextView.setTypeface(..). The values can be obtain from your item, or the position or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the ListViewAdapter. In my project I created a new class extending the ArrayAdapter:

```
class SummaryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DynformSummary> {
    static final int mViewResourceId = R.layout.dynformlist_item;
    final Context mContext;

    public SummaryListAdapter(Context context, DynformSummaryList items) {
        super(context, mViewResourceId, items);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            view = inflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        DynformSummary summary = getItem(position);
        if (summary != null) {
            TextView nameView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.dynformSummary_name);
            TextView createdOnView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.dynformSummary_createdOn);
            TextView itemSummaryView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.dynformSummary_itemSummary);
            java.text.DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext);

            String itemSummary = summary.getItemSummary();
            if (itemSummary == null || itemSummary.length() == 0) {
                itemSummary = mContext
                        .getString(R.string.placeholder_empty);
            }

            nameView.setText(summary.getName());
            createdOnView.setText(df.format(summary.getCreatedOn()));
            itemSummaryView.setText(itemSummary);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

In your case, you can create a separate layout xml for each different font or color, or you can edit the font / color at runtime in the getView method.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have a list view that holds textviews, when you set the text views text you are setting a CharSequence right? Well with a CharSequence you can add spans which you can make bold, underlined, italic, coloured, etc. Im pretty sure it will keep its style when you put it in a list view, no reason why it shouldn't, Also I think when you use a string the style goes away so you might want to use a CharSequence

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

using a span you can also dynamically change the looks without using hard coded XML